# Ethereum - does not exist/is not available error with web3

Tags: ethereum, whisper

I'm trying to get a simple whisper example running with web3 on geth console:

```
var f = web3.shh.filter({topics: ["qwerty"]})
f.get()
web3.shh.getMessages("qwerty")
web3.shh.post({topics: ["qwerty"], payload: "0x847a786376", ttl: "0x1E", workToProve: "0x9" })
```

But I'm getting these errors:

```
> f.get()
Filter ID Error: filter().get() can't be chained synchronous, please provide a callback for the get() method.
    at web3.js:3602:23
    at <anonymous>:1:1

> web3.shh.getMessages("qwerty")
TypeError: 'getMessages' is not a function
    at <anonymous>:1:1

> web3.shh.post({topics: ["qwerty"], payload: "0x847a786376", ttl: "0x1E", workToProve: "0x9" })
The method shh_post does not exist/is not available
    at web3.js:3119:20
    at web3.js:6023:15
    at web3.js:4995:36
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

Is the documentation not up to date or does it not run with my geth version (tried 1.4.5 and 1.5)?
Also get a "does not exist/is not available" error for `web3.shh.newIdentity()`

Comment: Whisper is in very early stages of development. You might get an answer from official sources if you try to ask on [Ethereum Stack Exchange](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/).